# Can't press enter in jshell on Linux-terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jshell

I'm using Xubuntu. When I start jshell in the terminal, I doesn't recognize when I press the enter key. Every other key gets detected normaly. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following in your terminal:

```
numlockx on
```

Now it will work. To make this permanent, let Xubuntu execute this after booting.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for laptop users without an number pad on their keyboard:

1. Plug in an extra keyboard with a number-pad.
2. Start jshell, try to press enter on your laptop keyboard.
3. If it still doesn't work: On the extra keyboard: press "Num" key with which you activate the number pad.
4. Now pressing enter on your laptop keyboard again.

It should work now, otherwise turn the numberpad off and on again and repeat step 4.

Don't know why it works that way, but it does.

Comment: This helped me when I was in an entirely stuck situation by killing gnome shell, having nothing but a terminal, and having the terminal apparently unresponsive to keyboard!  It turns out, in addition to having killed everything, I was also stuck due to numlock.